# Why returning column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am working with C# and I want to insert some values to my SQL Server database, here is my data base definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT 1000, 
    [FullName] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [Pseudo] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [Mail] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [Password] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [Organism] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
    [RegistredAt] DATETIME NULL, 
    [Confirmed] INT NULL
)
```

and this how I am trying to insert the values to the database using C#:

```
 SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(@FullName, @Pseudo, @Mail, @Password, @Organism, @RegistredAt, @Confirmed)", con);

 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FullName", FullName);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pseudo", Pseudo);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mail", Mail);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", Password);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Organism", Organism);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RegistredAt", DateTime.Now);
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Confirmed", Confirmed);

 con.Open();
 int i = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 con.Close();
```

When I execute the code, the instruction `command.ExecuteNonQuery();` returns an exception:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Where is the error?

Comment: Have you tried adding your columns into the query? 
Insert into Users(FullName, Pseudo, Mail, Password, Organism, RegisteredAt, Confirmed)...

Comment: Is this MSSQL? What version? I'm using SQL2016 and defaults are not available for identity columns... `Defaults cannot be created on columns with an IDENTITY attribute. Table 'Users', column 'Id'.`. Are you 100% sure your schema looks how you expect it to look? I guarantee that column is not an identity given the errors you are experiencing

Comment: With an actual identity column this test insert works as expected: `insert into users 
values ('fred', '123', '12312', '213213', '123123', '01 Jan 2016', 0)` - no column list required.

Comment: solved: it only need the remove `DEFAULT 1000` from the database definition

Comment: Now that you solved the current problem you need to stop storing passwords as plain text. Those values should be salted and hashed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You <strike>might</strike> need to supply the column names in your query:

```
INSERT INTO Users (FullName, Pseudo, Mail, Password, Organism, RegistredAt, Confirmed) 
VALUES (@FullName, @Pseudo, @Mail, @Password, @Organism, @RegistredAt, @Confirmed)
```

If you don't supply the column names, it assumes you want to use all columns, including the ID field. That's the reason for the error -- you're supplying 7 values for a table with 8 columns. Since you are using a subset, you need to specify them.

Also, I'm not sure if you are at a stage where it can be fixed, but you have a typo in "RegistredAt" -- it should be "Regist**e**redAt".

Comment: I have already tried it and it returns `{"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id',  column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}`

Comment: If that happens, your ID column cannot be an identity... are you sure your table definition is correct?

Comment: @MehdiBenHamida: You should not have the `Id` column specified anywhere in your code. If your table definition above is correct, this statement should work. Please edit into your question all versions of the code you've tried if it continues to fail.

Comment: solved: it only need the remove `DEFAULT 1000` from the database definition